# Split a string in ASP Javascript

Tags: asp-classic, jscript

I am trying to split a string from a recordset that is in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`.

So basically something like:

```
Homework.Fields.Item("DateDue").Value.split("/")
```

But that doesn't work, Normally I can do:

```
String(Homework.Fields.Item("DateDue").Value).split("/")
```

But using `String()` turns the value into a long thing like:

```
Wed Oct 26 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2011
```

Which I can't split.

All I need is the day `DD` part.

Is there away to bump topics as I still haven't got  working answer.

Comment: I give you mad props for using ASP Classic JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to use client side javascript anyway, to get the clients local time. So I just put the Homework....Value into a javascript Variable and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need to `Homework.Fields.Item("DateDue").Value.getDate()`

Comment: +1 for the pragmatic answer :) If the date is the only value needed, then use JavaScript's native `getDate()` function instead of splitting the string and trying to read the appropriate array item.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to parse date first from the value before calling getDate()?

DateTime.Parse(Homework.Fields.Item("DateDue").Value).getDate()?

Comment: It just comes back with:
Microsoft JScript runtime  error '800a1391'

'DateTime' is undefined